# Getting error 'undefined is not an object' when using substring with React Native

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native

I'm new with React Native.

As a matter of practice, I'm building a simple React Native app, where I'm connecting to HubSpot's API to retrieve some blog posts, show them and interact with them. This is going all right for now, but when I'm parsing the JSON, I come up with a field "publish_date" that contains a timestamp. For some reason this timestamp contains 3 extra numbers, I think this is for the timezone. Anyway, when I output the timestamp using 'react-timestamp', I use this value and I get a date way too far. So I thought to use substring to remove the last 3 digits and output the correct date.

This is part of the code that is failing:

```
renderRow(post) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: post.featured_image}} />
            <View style={styles.info}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{post.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.author}>Por {post.author_name}</Text>
                <Timestamp time={post.publish_date.substring(10)} component={Text} format='date' />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

render() {
    return(
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            style={styles.page}
         />
    );
}
```

When I run it, I get the next error:

[image: Error]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and this is all new to me. Yesterday I ran with the same error trying to use .replace(''), so I gave up and went for another solution. In this case I think I can't go for anything else.

Comment: Ok so I've been working on this a lot more time, and got some different result. I think maybe the problem is directly with the Timestamp module I installed... So I added a function **outside** my main class, called feed. I then in that function ran a code that divided my timestamp so I get a correct one, all went through, but then, when I call that inside the Timestamp module, I get the same error, but if I call a `<Text>{cts}</Text>` where **cts** is the result of the function, it shows correctly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after many time, not getting an answer and even opening an issue in the Git of the module, I decided to keep looking.

The thing with this is, that in fact my timestamp was in milliseconds and when converting it to milliseconds, something in the process makes the Timestamp module to crash. So, I decided to drop that and use another method.

It went like this:

```
var datePosted = new Date(post.publish_date).toString();
```

Now I get the correct date without the need of an outside module. Hope this helps anyone, but I don't think anyone in the world was facing this issue like me. Thanks all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try to log your post object and see if `"publish_date"` is defined,

according to the error, there is no `"publish_date"` attribute on the object post that is passed to the function renderRow, therefor, the call to substring is failing.

Comment: If I remove the substring function, I get a timestamp, therefor, the publish_date variable contains something. The problem is that it contains 3 extra digits, so if I convert that into a normal date format, I get a date from around the year 4000. That's why I want to use the substring function. I think the error comes from something else, because as I said, I tried to use the replace function with a simple string, and I get the exact same error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Extra three digits,  this sounds to me that you re getting a timestamp in milli seconds rather than seconds trying deviding it by 1000 and then converting it to a date, you should get a proper date i think.

Comment: I updated my code, I'm adding: `var date = post.publish_date; date = date / 1000;` and I'm getting this error now: "null is not an object (evaluating 'date.split')". I'm really getting frustrated about this.

Comment: this indeed is pretty frustrating.  try deleting all the Timestamp component and log all the post.publish_date and see if all post have that attribute if not, display the timestamp only for post that define it.

this as far as i can go without looking at the hole component and the post object structure.

Comment: I think this has to do with how am I trying to do javascript functions inside a React Component, as I'm not able to do this in any way I've tried. It has nothing to do with the information given by the API, as I've told before. Thank you for you time! :)